# Address of object in c++ function

Tags: c++, class, memory, pointers

the question is how to get pointer to self inside method of a class without touching `this`:

```
class Foo
{
   int a, b, c;
   void Print();
};
```

This way in common compiler I can do this refering to first data field:

```
void Foo::Print()
{
   cout << &a; // == this
}
```

But are there any ways to do this without data members when only function exists?

```
class Foo2
{
   void Print();
};
```

p.s. don't even ask me why do I need this :)

Comment: @JanKoester: Or rather, the object pointed to by `this`. (After all, `this` is a pointer, not an object :) )

Comment: You're still using `this` implicitly.  Do you just mean that you can't have the token `this` in your source code?  How about `th##is`?

Comment: @BenVoigt That's just theory about structure of class in memory :)

Comment: @Ockonal: No, the compiler converts any unqualified usage of non-static members to a reference to `this`.  If you don't believe me, try using non-static members inside a lambda without capturing `this`.

Comment: @BenVoigt you didn't understand me.

Comment: "When an *id-expression* (5.1) that is not part of a class member access syntax (5.2.5) and not used to form a pointer to member (5.3.1) is used in a member of class `X` in a context where `this` can be used (5.1.1), if name lookup (3.4) resolves the name in the id-expression to a non-static non-type member of some class C, and if either the *id-expression* is potentially evaluated or `C` is `X` or a base class of `X`, the *id-expression* is transformed into a class member access expression (5.2.5) using (*this) (9.3.2) as the *postfix-expression* to the left of the `.` operator." -- 9.3.1p3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a POD class with at least one data member, the address of the class-type object is the same as the address of its first data member.  This is because there can be no unnamed padding bytes before the first data member of a POD struct type.  [In C++11, the rules are a bit different; I believe that this is true for all *standard layout* class types.  I am not entirely familiar with the rules, however.]

For any other class type, there is no way to do this.

Comment: I think the rule you're looking for is 9.2p20.  "A pointer to a standard-layout struct object, suitably converted using a `reinterpret_cast`, points to its initial member (or if that member is a bit-field, then to the unit in which it resides) and vice versa."

Comment: @BenVoigt:  Yes, that's what I was looking for, thanks.  I don't have a copy of the C++ Standard at work anymore; I find that not having it helps me stay focused on work and not get distracted trying to answer language-lawyer questions on Stack Overflow :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
class Foo2
{
   void Print();
};

#define OBJADDR(x) (th##x##s)

void Foo2::Print()
{
    int i; // red herring, but the name MUST be `i`
    std::cout << OBJADDR(i);
    i; // to get rid of compiler warning about unused local variable
};
```

Comment: What is `i` inside `Print` call?

Comment: @Ockonal: Do you like that version better?

Comment: Ha! Very funny. Are you coming to Redmond for the MVP Summit?

Comment: @James: I wish, but no time.  But I've made up my mind to definitely go next year (if I'm renewed in April).

Answer (score 1):

If your class has no data members then technically, instances of the class don't even exist. For convenience only, they are required to have size of at least 1 byte and have unique `this` pointers. If you inherit from a class with no data members, its size collapses to 0 and it disappears.

So no, there isn't any way to get the `this` pointer without using the `this` pointer. A less pragmatic version of C++ wouldn't even have `this` pointers for these objects, as they would have size 0.

Answer (score 0):

You can *probably* hack it using the `offsetof` macro

```
void Foo::Print()
{
   cout << static_cast<char *>(&a) - offsetof(Foo, a);
}
```

if you can't safely assume `&a` is the start.

So ... why do you need to do this?

Comment: It's a data member of Foo, and we're apparently ignoring the fact it's identical to `this->a`